# Hugo theme link refers to container port in Docker/Nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, port, hugo

I've got a simple static site, generated with Hugo, that I'm building to a Docker container running Nginx. Nginx is listening on port 90. I'm encountering strange behavior where certain links try to open the *container* port rather than the host port (in the case of `localhost`, it's 8000). So for example, this link:

```
<a href="/documents">Docs</a>
```

...when moused-over shows that it will attempt to open `localhost:8000/documents`, which is correct, but when clicked it attempts instead to open `http://localhost:90/documents/` (If I manually change the URL in the browser to `http://localhost:8000/documents/`, it responds fine.)

What makes this even stranger:

1. Only certain links, specifically in the header menu, do this.
2. I've used dozens of Hugo themes, and I've only encountered this issue with one of them: [ZDoc](https://github.com/zzossig/hugo-theme-zdoc). Could it be specific to this theme? That seems strange to me.

What could be causing this? I'm struggling to even know what this phenomenon is called. "Host/container port confusion"?

I'm certain it's not a misconfiguration of Nginx or Docker. I'm exposing port 90 properly in my Dockerfile:

```
EXPOSE 90
```

`nginx.conf` is set to listen on that port:

```
http {
    include    /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    sendfile on;
    server {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html/;
        index index.html;
        server_name localhost;
        listen 90;
    }
}
```

And I'm starting the Docker container with the host port 8000 forwarding to the port Nginx is listening on:

```
docker run --name my-simple-site -p 8000:90 -d simple-site

$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID    IMAGE          COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                   NAMES
de9cd1526034    simple-site    "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   41 minutes ago   Up 41 minutes   0.0.0.0:8000->90/tcp    my-simple-site
```

Answer (score 0):

Strangely, the fix for this was to change the link to point directly to the file: `<a href="/documents/index.html">Docs</a>`

I'm unclear why and would love some insight into this. Does Nginx infer a port when pointing to a directory?